# How to add reflection definition to read json files on web game

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I have a game which I deployed for desktop and android, I can read json data and create my levels, but the problem is, when it comes to reading json files from web app, I get an error that logs, cannot read the json file, I researched a lot and I found out that I should add my json config class to configurations, I added this line to gameName.gwt.xml, which is in core folder

```
<extend-configuration-property name="gdx.reflect.include" value="com.las.get.level.LevelConfig"/>
```

but it did not work out too, I have no idea where should I place this line, or where should I change to make my web app work, so I can read json files

Comment: Try it in the gwt.xml file of your HTML project.

Comment: is it /html/war/WEB-INF/classes/com/las/get/ ? there are two definition files in that folder, should I add this line two both of them ? the file names are, GdxDefinition.gwt.xml and GdxDefinitionSuperdev.gwt.xml, thank you

Comment: No, those are just copied files. You need to put it in the *.gwt.xml files in html/src/your/package/

Comment: @noone I am sorry for asking too many questions :) my json config class is in core folder, should I copy it to html folder ? thank you again

Comment: No, your projects should be setup that it will automatically copy all necessary classes from the core project.

Comment: still does not happen, I am trying to solve this issue for like 3 days now, I have got the cancer now, If you could help me more I will be real glad, here is my definition file contents, http://pastebin.com/917C3hMd, http://pastebin.com/wCy8B4Su, those are the files inside my html/src folder

Comment: That was how I solved this problem some time ago. Did you recompile/repackage everything? I advice you to delete the whole `html/build` folder and do it again. I had the problem of it not getting cleaned up correctly and all changes I did, didn't apply after a rebuild because of that.

Comment: I deleted my whole folder and rebuild again, bu does not seem to work again :) bad luck I guess :), can you check my pastebin contents, if you have free time of course, I know I have bothered you so much

Comment: It looks okay to me, one last suggestion would be to only use your main package `com.picarex.feedthefish` without the subpackage or class. That's how I did it. Other than that I have no idea anymore.

Comment: did not work out too, thank you for your help and kindness